# What is the difference between FPS and UPS and should I keep track of UPS on my game loop?

Tags: performance, loops, frame-rate, game-development, game-loop

I was searching for ways to improve my game looping and how to implement more performance options to the players when I found the term *UPS*. I know it means updates per seconds, but how it affects performance? And should I worry about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have an extremely simple game with a single thread and a basic loop, like "`while(running) { get_input(); update_world_state(); update_video(); }`". In this case you end up with "UPS = FPS" (and no reason to track UPS separately from FPS); and if the GPU is struggling to keep up the entire game slows down (e.g. if you're getting 15 frames per second, then things that have nothing to do with graphics might take 4 times longer than they should, even when you have 8 CPUs doing nothing while waiting for GPU to finish).

For one alternative, what if you had 2 threads, where one thread does "`while(running) { get_input(); update_world_state(); }`" and the other thread does "`while(running) { update_video(); }`"? In this case there's no reason to expect UPS to have anything to do with FPS. The problem here is that most games aren't smart enough to handle variable timing, so you'd end up with something more like "`while(running) { get_input(); update_world_state(); wait_until_next_update_starts(); }`" to make sure that the game can't run too fast (e.g. cars that are supposed to be moving at a speed of 20 Km per hour moving at 200 Km per hour because `update_world_state()` is being called too often). Depending on things and stuff, you might get 60 UPS (regardless of what FPS is); but if the CPU can't keep up the game can/will still slow down and you might get 20 UPS (regardless of what FPS is). Of course there's no point updating the video if the world state hasn't changed; so you'd want the graphics loop to be more like "`while(running) { wait_for_world_state_update(); update_video(); }`", where `wait_for_world_state_update()` makes sure FPS <= UPS (and where `wait_for_world_state_update()` returns immediately without any delay when UPS is keeping up).

The next step beyond this is "tickless". In this case you might have one high priority thread monitoring user input and assigning timestamps to input events (e.g. "at time = 12356 the user fired their main weapon") and storing them in a list. Then you might have a second (lower priority, to avoid messing up the accuracy of the user input timestamps) thread with a main loop like "`while(running) { next_frame_time = estimate_when__next_frame_will_actually_be_visible(); update_world_state_until(next_frame_time); update_video(); }`", where `update_world_state_until()` uses a whole pile of maths to predict what the game state will be at a specific point in time (and consumes the list of stored user input events while taking their timestamps into account). In this case UPS doesn't really make any sense (you'd only care about FPS). This is also much more complicated (due to the maths involved in calculating the world state at any point in time); but the end result is like having "infinite UPS" without the overhead of updating the world state more than once per frame; and it allows you to hide any graphics latency (e.g. things seen 16.66 ms later than they should); which makes it significantly better than other options (much smoother, significantly less likely for performance problems to cause simulation speed variations, etc).